# I have two System informations display

Tags: server, upgrade

Hey! I have upgraded from 10.04 to 10.10 using the the 
apt-get dist-upgrade command.

Everything went ok (at least for now everything seems to be working) but now when I login via ssh I get two system informations display, the first from 10.10 abd the second from 10.04.1 LTS

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody @ http://wwww.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10046052

recommended to check `/etc/motd` (Message of the day)

`gksudo gedit /etc/motd` should do the trick